# Linked List, keep getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to add Point into a linked list, in order to keep track of the frequency of each data entry. Everytime I run this code it gives me a NullPointerException. I don;t understand why, to me it seems as if after it adds the frequency it creates a gap but I cant seem to fix it.

```
if(firstNode == null)
    {
        addPair = new Pair(aData, 1);
        firstNode = new Node(null, addPair, null);
        lastNode = firstNode;
        currentNode = firstNode;
        numberOfNodes++;
    }
    else
    {
        currentNode=firstNode;
        for(int count = 0; count<numberOfNodes; count++)
            {
                if(currentNode.data.fst().equals(aData))
                {                                  
                    addPair = new Pair(aData,currentNode.data.freq()+1);
                    if(count==0)
                        firstNode= new Node(currentNode,addPair,null);
                    currentNode = new Node(currentNode,addPair,null);
                    break;
                }
                if(count == (numberOfNodes-1) && currentNode.data.fst() !=(aData))
                    {
                            addPair = new Pair(aData,1);
                            Node newNode = new Node(currentNode, addPair, null);
                            currentNode.next = newNode;
                            lastNode = newNode;
                            numberOfNodes++;
                            break;
                        }
                        currentNode = currentNode.next;
                    }

    }

    numberOfEntries++;

     private class Node
{
    private Node previous;
    private Pair data;
    private Node next;

    private Node(Node previousNode, Pair<T,Integer> addPair, Node nextNode)
    {
        previous = previousNode;
        data = addPair;
        next = nextNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your stacktrace?

Comment: How about showing us the `Node` class?  You've basically asked us to find a needle in a haystack, but only given us a handful of hay from the top of the stack, to look at.

Comment: Added the Node class

Comment: Where do you get the NPE ?

Comment: @SklogW I get it at the line if(currentNode.data.fst().equals(aData))

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a NPE at the line `if(currentNode.data.fst().equals(aData))` then either `currentNode == null` or `currentNode.data == null` or `currectNode.data.fst() == null`. The first thing to do in diagnosing the problem is to find out which of these is the case. I suggest you put the following statements before this line and rerun your code:

```
assert currentNode != null;
assert currentNode.data != null;
assert currentNode.data.fst() != null;
```

Apart from that diagnosis there are a number of ways you could make your code safer. Firstly you really have no need to use a count to iterate through your linked list. Much safer would be to end when the `next` pointer is `null`:

```
for (Node current = firstNode; current != null; current = current.next) {
    if (current.data.equals(aData)) {
        // increment counter
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in this line

```
firstNode= new Node(currentNode,addPair,null);
```

When you increase frequency of first node you are not setting the next `Node`, so you got list of only one node, but with size of many. Similar problem with line

```
currentNode = new Node(currentNode,addPair,null);
```

Also all first `if` statement is wrong. You are corrupting links in the list, it should be something like this

```
if (currentNode.data.fst().equals(aData)) {
    addPair = new Pair(aData, currentNode.data.freq() + 1);
    // create new node
    Node c = new Node(currentNode.previous, addPair, currentNode.next);
    // set links to new node
    if (currentNode.previous != null) {
        currentNode.previous.next = c;
    }
    if (currentNode.next != null) {
        currentNode.next.previous = c;
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        firstNode = c;
    } 
    break;
}
```

To simplify your code and decrease possible errors I could recommend to write some function like `incFrequency()` in `Pair` class. Then in the loop do something like this

```
if (currentNode.data.fst().equals(aData)) {
    currentNode.data.incFrequency();
    break;
} else if(count == (numberOfNodes-1) && currentNode.data.fst() !=(aData)) {
    // add new node to the end
}
```

Also you could rewrite you `for` loop

```
currentNode = firstNode;
// iterate through list
while (currentNode != null) {
    // process currentNode 
    ...
    // move to the next node
    currentNode = currentNode.next;
}
```